# Custom naming strategy and @JsonProperty in Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I'm trying to override property name specified in `@JsonProperty` during serialization, but get both old and new named properties in the resulting json.

Entity:

```
class Bean {

    @JsonProperty("p")
    String prop;

    @JsonCreator
    Bean(@JsonProperty("p") String prop) {
        this.prop = prop;
    }
}
```

Serializing code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(new PropertyNamingStrategy() {
            @Override
            public String nameForField(MapperConfig<?> config, AnnotatedField field, String defaultName) {
                return "prop";
            }
        });
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(new Bean("test")));
```

Results in:

```
{"p":"test","prop":"test"}
```

Accrding to Jackson's code, this happens because constructor parameters are also annotated with `@JsonProperty`. I'm using Jackson 1.9.5.

Is there a way to disable constructor parameters and get `{"prop":"test"}` ?
Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Why are you mixing everything? Just put `@JsonProperty` over your field without a `value` attribute. If the field is called `prop`, that's how it will be serialized.

Comment: "Mixing" is not a right word. I have classes with `@JsonProperty` and would like to create another `ObjectMapper` with non default naming strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to directly disable annotations, but if you want to block their effects, you can sub-class `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector`, and override logic used for finding `@JsonProperty` annotation (or `@JsonCreator`).